# MySQL,PHP: count results per condition + get the total result that satisfies the conditions

Tags: php, mysql

### querytest table:

1. xxx  |   yyy
2. 999  | 888
3. 999 | 787
4. 111 | 222

### query:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE WHEN XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]8[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count999,
       SUM(CASE WHEN XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]2[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count111
    FROM querytest
    WHERE 
    ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]8[0-9]') 
    OR 
    ( XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]2[0-9]')
```

### result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 999
    [xxx] => 999
    [1] => 888
    [yyy] => 888
    [2] => 2
    [Count999] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [Count111] => 1
)
```

### clarification:

I'm using php.and i want a query that

- let me know how many results I can get from ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY
  RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]') and how many results i can get from ( XXX LIKE
  '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]') and so on. like in the previous query.
- gets me all the results like if im using this query:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM querytest
> WHERE 
> ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]8[0-9]') 
> OR 
> ( XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]2[0-9]')
> ```

### my question

how can I combine the two previous points into one query? plus the ability of using LIMIT and ORDER with the second point.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make separate queries, or use UNION.